# Ever encountered this "http://mattker.hu/images/image.php" in scripts in your site?

Tags: web-hosting, website, hacking

My site was hacked.
Most html and javascript files in my site were modified to included the link in the question title.
What strategies should I employ to reduce the likelihood of my site being hacked again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Restore from a known good backup

2) Change all passwords, this includes passwords for any service accounts you might have.

3) Double check your firewall config and disable any services you aren't actually using

This is to get you back up and running now. To prevent it from happening again you need to find out how it happened. Was it a brute force? Was it some exploit on an unpatched package? Etc Etc. You need to look through your logs and discover their attack vector.